# How to use a variable in where clause in python to access sql

Tags: python, mysql

```py
u=int(input('   ENTER YOUR CHOICE(1-6)  : '))

sql_select_Query = 'select * from hotel **where H_ID =u'**
mycur.execute (sql_select_Query)

dip=mycur.fetchall()
for x in dip:
   print(x,'\n')
```

getting error as
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'u' in 'where clause'

Doing from PYTHON
u is the input from user. how to include it in where clause  of sql

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a placeholder in the query (for MySQL that's usually `%s`) and then pass the variable separately to `.execute()`:

```
u = int(input(' ENTER YOUR CHOICE(1-6) : ')) 
sql_select_Query = 'select * from hotel where H_ID = %s'

mycur.execute(sql_select_Query, (u,)) 
dip = mycur.fetchall()
for x in dip:
    print(x, '\n')
```

Comment: Apologies, the placeholder is `%s`, not `?`.

Comment: but i didnt understanding ,sorry.12th std student

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for me is put a `f` before the string quotes, like

`f"the result is {your_variable}"`

[in code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G18xu.png)

unfortunately this just works in >= python3.7. But you can also use `.format`.

`"the result is {your_variable}".format(your_variable=0)`

[in code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag8dr.png)

Your script would be

`sql_select_Query = f'select * from hotel where H_ID = {u}'`

or

`sql_select_Query = 'select * from hotel where H_ID = {u}'.format(u=u)`

Comment: Please don't do this! Using f-strings or `.format()` or similar for SQL queries is a major cause of security holes (called "SQL injection"). Always use a placeholder and pass the variables separately to `.execute()` so it can deal with them safely.

Comment: @sabik I use the f-string for query in my project. But there is a validation, removing some characters like ' and ", and there is no direct interativity with users. Is there also a problem? I never heard about that

Comment: In practice, reasoning out and documenting why f-strings are OK in each particular case will be more work (and more error-prone) than always using placeholders and passing the variables separately. Any future change to the code will involve extra effort to confirm that it's still OK, with the risk of getting it wrong. Meanwhile, using placeholders is simple, straightforward, standard and safe.

Comment: In your particular case, since you're removing some characters, there probably is a problem — that's not a reliable approach.